# Efficient data structure for nearest neighbour search in a tiled context

Tags: geometry, geospatial, computational-geometry

I am looking for a datastructure to store irregular elevation data {xi,yi,zi} that facilitates fast look-up of points within a xy range.

From what I gather a kd tree should be suitable for this? And also fairly simple to implement?

However the number of points in the elevation dataset may be enormous. It may therefore not be possible to process all points in one go. Instead I aim to divide the xy region into tiles and process each tile separately:

[image]

The points within the green rectangle are those needed for tile 1. When I move into tile 2 I will need the points within a green rectangle centered around tile 2. The 2 rightmost point in the green rectangle around tile 1 will still be needed. The other points could be swapped out of memory if needed. In addition 4 more points will be needed for tile 2. 
A kd tree may therefore not be optimal since this would require me to rebuild the complete tree for each new tile? Would a R-tree be a better choice?

The point themselves should be stored on disk in some clever format and read into memory just before they are needed. Before I start processing tile 1, I could tell the data structure maintaining the points, that next I will be needing tile 2 and it could then begin to read the necessary points from disk in a separate thread.
I was considering using smaller tiles for loading points into the datastructure. For instance the points in the figure could be divided into 16x16 tiles.

Are there any libraries in C/C++ that implement this functionality?

Comment: Hi High Performance Mark! The points are fairly but not completely uniform. Yes dynamic updating is a concern.

Comment: Do you need to delete points, or only add dynamically?

Comment: Hi AlexWien! I need to delete points when the datastructure is running out of memory.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for range queues and not nearest neighbor queries. It also seems like you might be too set on the existing tiles. Seems like you could simply have the tiles be a regular grid. Thus instead of trying to fit the outlying points into the current titles, you just create 7-8 new tiles (a tile just being defined by it's x-y start and end). You can recursively divide the grid into smaller sections where needed. Another option might be to use a quad-tree, as sounds like it's close to what you are looking for in terms of being able to remove points if needed.